Brass faucet cartridge will not budge and I have now made it harder to remove. Seeking extreme solutions
I have a brass faucet in my bathroom that barely turns. It weeps a bit and so it is time to replace the catridge. Unfortunately, it is corroded and stuck. I applied PB blaster and WD-40 and waited all day, and then used a deep socket that fits, but the corrosion and softness of the brass catridge slipped and now I have a rough uneven mess that my pipewrench, vice grips and angry stares will not loosen.
What are the extreme options to remove the cartridge? I would replace the whole faucet but it was quite expensive 15 years ago and the remaining fixtures in the bathroom all match.
Here is what I am thinking of trying:

remove the faucet and soak in wd-40 for many days.
wrap faucet in duct tape and put in bench vise, grind new 'faces' to get vice grip on and try again.
attempt to remove by gripping stem of catridge (I am expecting this to fail).
give up and only wash my hands with hot water.

This is a before picture after I tried a first wrench, but before I ripped it to shreds trying to undo it.


might be left  handed thread

From your picture you have been trying to turn the nut by gripping on the corners. This is evident by the shiny corners. You need to turn the nut using force on the flat sides.  For that you need a six point thin wall deep socket

Get the exact size you need, (it may be metric) and probably will be 3/8 drive.  Use downward pressure on the ratchet wrench to keep the socket seated, as you turn counter clockwise.
If you cannot get the nut off by that method, your other option is to split the nut to remove it.  Then the issue becomes trying to find a replacement nut.

Box end wrench may work too.

Only if it is 6 point and it is more difficult to keep pressed down to prevent slippage.

Yes I have tried these options. I used a 5/8” deep socket with a breaker bar and the brass nut, which is part of the cartridge, and maybe I’m not capable but it warped the nut (which is very shallow) instead. That is why I am asking about “extreme” solutions.

Is the socket a 6 point and not 12 point?  Did you use force to hold it down in position?  Are you sure the nut is 5/8 and not 15 or 16 mm. The flats do not show that any force was exerted on them , only the corners.

I seem to remember one faucet which had one of the valve stems with reverse threading, to prevent accidentally exchanging the hot and cold and as a result having them rotate the wrong directions. I don't remember whether it was the hot or cold that they did this to, but you might want to try turning the "wrong" direction and seeing if it moves.
Since you asked for extreme solutions, remember that you can replace the entire faucet.
(Digression: I found that replacing the faucet on a tiny bathroom basin with one that had a high goose-neck spout tremendously improved the sink's usability. It did require giving up the built-in stopper control, but that had failed anyway; no loss.)
